# Missing Libraries or Incorrect code? Android Studio, APK crashes

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-studio

I am trying to simply get a fragment to display on the Activity, before adding the methods for the spinners everything worked, after doing so nothing worked? I tried downloading the support Libraries through SDK manager to see if that would fix it as I can only guess thats what the LogCat is referring too, can anyone potentially uncover whats happening here?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.****.testfragments3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private ArrayList<String> list1;
    private ArrayList<String> list2;
    private ArrayList<String> list3;

    Spinner s1,s2,s3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());

        if(sp1.contentEquals("Nitrates")) {
            list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list2)));
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list2);
            dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
        }

        if(sp1.contentEquals("Phosphates")) {
            list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list1)));
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
            dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
        }

        if(sp1.contentEquals("Alkalinity")) {
            list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list1)));
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
            dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
        }

        if(sp1.contentEquals("Calcium")) {
            list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list1)));
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
            dataAdapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter4.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter4);
        }

        if(sp1.contentEquals("Magnesium")) {
            list3 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list3)));
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list3);
            dataAdapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter5.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter5);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
    02-29 10:50:20.140 24382-24382/com.example.nparr.testfragments3 E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    02-29 10:50:20.140 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
    02-29 10:50:20.140 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
    02-29 10:50:20.150 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
    02-29 10:50:20.181 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/fd: BootstrapApplication created. Android package is com.example.****.testfragments3, real application class is null.
    02-29 10:50:20.191 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 6881 (UTF_8) in Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets;
    02-29 10:50:20.191 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0006
    02-29 10:50:20.191 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 V/fd: Cannot find external resources, not patching them in
    02-29 10:50:20.191 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/fd: Resource override is null
    02-29 10:50:20.201 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 V/fd: Cannot find newer dex classes, not patching them in
    02-29 10:50:20.201 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/fd: No override .dex files found
    02-29 10:50:20.201 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
    02-29 10:50:20.201 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1706 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
    02-29 10:50:20.201 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x01cd
    02-29 10:50:20.201 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/fd: Starting server socket listening for package com.example.****.testfragments3 on android.net.LocalSocketAddress@421fec28
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/fd: Started server for package com.example.****.testfragments3
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getSystemService, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 424: Landroid/content/Context;.getSystemService (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0049
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.stopLockTask, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 223: Landroid/app/Activity;.stopLockTask ()V
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x00b7
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 214 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lcom/example/****/testfragments3/MainActivity;
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x00ef
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 407: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x00ff
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onVisibleBehindCanceled, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 146: Landroid/app/Activity;.onVisibleBehindCanceled ()V
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x010f
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 223 (Landroid/os/UserHandle;) in Lcom/example/****/testfragments3/MainActivity;
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x011b
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 150: Landroid/app/Activity;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0135
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 214 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lcom/example/****/testfragments3/MainActivity;
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0198
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 175 (Landroid/media/session/MediaController;) in Lcom/example/****/testfragments3/MainActivity;
    02-29 10:50:20.211 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x01b0
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1866 (Landroid/widget/Toolbar;) in Lcom/example/****/testfragments3/MainActivity;
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x01ba
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.releaseInstance, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 157: Landroid/app/Activity;.releaseInstance ()Z
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x02db
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onActivityReenter, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 98: Landroid/app/Activity;.onActivityReenter (ILandroid/content/Intent;)V
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x02f2
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 476: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0347
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.createConfigurationContext, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 456: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createConfigurationContext (Landroid/content/res/Configuration;)Landroid/content/Context;
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x03d5
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView (Landroid/view/View;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View; from Lcom/example/****/testfragments3/MainActivity;)
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1987: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView (Landroid/view/View;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0430
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getVoiceInteractor, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 77: Landroid/app/Activity;.getVoiceInteractor ()Landroid/app/VoiceInteractor;
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x048e
    02-29 10:50:20.221 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.231 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x07e6
    02-29 10:50:20.231 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: DexOpt: resolve class illegal access: Lcom/example/ 0x0002
    02-29 10:50:20.361 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
    02-29 10:50:20.361 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14713: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
    02-29 10:50:20.361 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
    02-29 10:50:20.361 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
    02-29 10:50:20.361 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 666: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    02-29 10:50:20.361 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    02-29 10:50:20.371 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
    02-29 10:50:20.371 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 688: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    02-29 10:50:20.371 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    02-29 10:50:20.411 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performSaveInstanceState (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V from Lcom/example/****/testfragments3/frag1;)
    02-29 10:50:20.411 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.frag1.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.411 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1938: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performSaveInstanceState (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
    02-29 10:50:20.411 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0041
    02-29 10:50:20.411 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.restoreViewState (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V from Lcom/example/****/testfragments3/frag1;)
    02-29 10:50:20.411 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.frag1.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.411 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1943: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.restoreViewState (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
    02-29 10:50:20.411 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0054
    02-29 10:50:20.421 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performCreateView (Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Landroid/view/ViewGroup;Landroid/os/Bundle;)Landroid/view/View; from Lcom/example/****/testfragments3/frag1;)
    02-29 10:50:20.421 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.frag1.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.421 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1928: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performCreateView (Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Landroid/view/ViewGroup;Landroid/os/Bundle;)Landroid/view/View;
    02-29 10:50:20.421 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0080
    02-29 10:50:20.421 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performPrepareOptionsMenu (Landroid/view/Menu;)Z from Lcom/example/****/testfragments3/frag1;)
    02-29 10:50:20.421 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performPrepareOptionsMenu, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.frag1.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.421 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1935: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performPrepareOptionsMenu (Landroid/view/Menu;)Z
    02-29 10:50:20.421 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0089
    02-29 10:50:20.421 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performStop ()V from Lcom/example/****/testfragments3/frag1;)
    02-29 10:50:20.421 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStop, referenced from method com.example.****.testfragments3.frag1.access$super
    02-29 10:50:20.421 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1940: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performStop ()V
    02-29 10:50:20.471 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 409: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    02-29 10:50:20.471 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
    02-29 10:50:20.481 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatPopupWindow.showAsDropDown
    02-29 10:50:20.481 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15394: Landroid/widget/PopupWindow;.showAsDropDown (Landroid/view/View;III)V
    02-29 10:50:20.481 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000d
    02-29 10:50:20.491 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
    02-29 10:50:20.491 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    02-29 10:50:20.491 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41541438)
    02-29 10:50:20.501 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.****.testfragments3/com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController(FragmentManager.java:2025)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:276)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:61)
                                                                                          at com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5048)
                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2052)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771) 
                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    02-29 10:50:34.085 24382-24382/com.example.****.testfragments3 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24382 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling super.onCreate twice, and actually also setContentView. Remove the excessive calls and you should be fine.

The stack trace was pretty clear by telling you that you were already attached when line 28 was executed.

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController(FragmentManager.java:2025) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:95) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:276) at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:61) at com.example.****.testfragments3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)`

I reckon if you'd paid close attention to that log and gone looking at line 28 you would probably have noticed what was going on. This has nothing to do with missing libraries.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice this and to be perfectly honest I didn't even understand that was an issue, I am so new to Android Development and just learning. I appreciate you taking the time to look at that for me.

Comment: Glad to help, we are all new at some point! WRT android, I *strongly* recommend you not just jump into code and try to squeeze something together from bits and.pieces. Read the most fundamental parts of the developer guide, and do so thoroughly. Trust me, take the time to do this or you will have problems. For example, the rule that all lifecycle methods of an activity must call through to super is documented here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle but as I said, I would recommend reading Google's development guide from the start.

Comment: Also, learn to interpret logs so that you can quickly see where somethinh went wrong, and what happened. In case of a crash there are almost always excellent leads in the stacktrace.